# Pre-render a video in PhotoShop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, video

How can I load a video in the ram for smooth scrubbing in Photoshop? While scrubbing manually a green bar shows up at the top of the timeline. When I scrub very slowly, everything is loaded into the ram. But there should be a command for this right?

Comment: Hi Wout, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally found it myself by just trying everything like a mad man. The solution is:

```
ctrl + click on the play button in the timeline
```

Hope that helps someone!